# vimrc file won't apply textwidth settings

Tags: unix, vim, command-line, text-width

While in a terminal session I can do

```
:set textwidth=9999
```

And I receive what I want (which is lines of text which can go to the end of my computer screen)

I created a file called ~/.vimrc which contains the line

```
set textwidth=9999
```

And I get no results from from this

Comment: After launching vim with this in your `.vimrc`, run `:verbose set textwidth`.  This should tell you the current setting of `textwidth` as well as where it was set.

Comment: @RandyMorris Are you saying I type ':verbose set textwidth' in my .vimrc file and this will make it longer? I want my textwidth to be permanently set to '9999'

Comment: No, I'm saying to run that manually after vim is open.  This will tell us whether or not something is overriding your `.vimrc`.  This isn't a fix, it's a debugging step.

Comment: textwidth=78
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vimrc
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: Hmm, it looks like maybe your `.vimrc` isn't being read.  Run `:scriptnames` (again, manually) and see if it is showing in the list of files that have been sourced.

Comment: Do you use `evim` or `vim -y`?

Comment: @RandyMorris It's tenth on the list and theres about 24 after it under /usr/share/vim whereas mine is only under ~/.vimrc  10: ~/.vimrc
 11: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim

Comment: This Q **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://vi.stackexchange.com OR http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: Also, to disable wrapping, use `set textwidth=0` -- https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `~/.vimrc` is loaded as the very first configuration (cp `:help initialization`); after that, other configuration and plugins are read, and any of those may change the option again. You can check with

```
:verbose set textwidth?
```

and get the list of configuration scripts via

```
:scriptnames
```

Ideally, you're able to disable the overriding of the option value. As a workaround, you can also re-initialize the option at the end of configuration, by putting the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * set textwidth=9999
```

The `'textwidth'` option is a *buffer-local* option. *Filetype plugins* may adapt this setting. There are ways to override filetype-specific settings (`:help after-directory`), too.